# How to solve multi part identifier error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When execute my below query I'm getting this error:

---

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The multi-part identifier "LEAS.BLDGID" could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The multi-part identifier "LEAS.LEASID" could not be bound. 
>   **when i am running the upper part of the query getting the error !!(need only the 1st part as the data is coming wrong !!****

```
SELECT 1 
    FROM NOTE 
    LEFT JOIN INSL ON INSL.TABLEID =  'LEAS' AND INSL.TABLEKEY = NOTE.LEASID 
    WHERE NOTE.BLDGID = LEAS.BLDGID AND NOTE.LEASID = LEAS.LEASID AND NOTE.REF1 = 'INSURAN'  
        AND NOTE.REF2 = 'REMIND' AND NOTE.ACTIONED <> 'C' AND NOTE.NOTEDATE = INSL.INSLEND 
        AND  INSL.INSLEND < '2016-04-07' AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM INSL I2 
            WHERE I2.TABLEKEY = INSL.TABLEKEY AND I2.TABLEID = INSL.TABLEID AND I2.INSLCODE = INSL.INSLCODE 
                    AND I2.INSLEND > INSL.INSLEND
            )
```

full query is

```
    SELECT TOP 301
        LEAS.LEASID ,
        LEAS.BLDGID ,
        LEAS.SUITID ,
        SUIT.ADDRESS ,
        LEAS.OCCPNAME ,
        LEAS.RENTSTRT ,
        LEAS.EXPIR ,
        LEAS.VACATE ,
        LEAS.STOPBILLDATE ,
        LEAS.INSEXP ,
        LEAS.OCCPSTAT ,
        LEAS.PRTSTAT ,
        LEAS.PERMITCR ,
        LEAS.LEASSTOP ,
        LEAS.MAXLATE ,
        LEAS.LASTDATE ,
        LEAS.USERID ,
        LEAS.EXCL5YR ,
        LEAS.STYPID ,
        LEAS.REPFREQ ,
        LEAS.REQADJ ,
        LEAS.PCTGBASE ,
        LEAS.NATURAL ,
        LEAS.NUMCOPY ,
        LEAS.GENERATION ,
        LEAS.ADDLSPACE ,
        LEAS.PRIMARYCHGS ,
        LEAS.HEADLEAS ,
        LEAS.DEPARTMENT ,
        LEAS.PREPAYTAXTERM ,
        LEAS.HEAD ,
        LEAS.INVOICEGRP ,
        LEAS.LEASE_YRS ,
        LEAS.LEASE_MTHS ,
        LEAS.LEASE_DAYS ,
        LEAS.INVPRINT ,
        LEAS.CASUALCARPARKS ,
        LEAS.TAXEXEMPT ,
        LEAS.AUTOEXCEPTION ,
        LEAS.FASBEXCEPTION ,
        LEAS.PERCENTRENT ,
        LEAS.INV_AUTOE ,
        LEAS.SMT_AUTOE ,
        LEAS.LATEPAYER
FROM    LEAS ,
        SUIT
WHERE   SUIT.BLDGID = LEAS.BLDGID
        AND SUIT.SUITID = LEAS.SUITID
        AND ( LEAS.BLDGID IN ( '140056', '140063', '140070', '140104',
                               '140137', '140138', '140151', '140253',
                               '140345', '140419', '140444', '140508',
                               '140509', '140522', '140542', '140546',
                               '140570', '140575', '140579', '140590',
                               '140623', '140625', '140626', '140662',
                               '140666', '140670', '140760', '140763',
                               '140788', '140789', '140793', '140799',
                               '140811', '140852', '140858', '140861',
                               '140867', '140875', '140880', '140881',
                               '140917', '140938' )
              AND LEAS.OCCPSTAT IN ( 'C', 'N' )
              AND EXISTS ( SELECT   1
                           FROM     NOTE
                                    LEFT JOIN INSL ON INSL.TABLEID = 'LEAS'
                                                      AND INSL.TABLEKEY = NOTE.LEASID
                           WHERE    NOTE.BLDGID = LEAS.BLDGID
                                    AND NOTE.LEASID = LEAS.LEASID
                                    AND NOTE.REF1 = 'INSURAN'
                                    AND NOTE.REF2 = 'REMIND'
                                    AND NOTE.ACTIONED <> 'C'
                                    AND NOTE.NOTEDATE = INSL.INSLEND
                                    AND INSL.INSLEND < '2016-04-07'
                                    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                                                     FROM   INSL I2
                                                     WHERE  I2.TABLEKEY = INSL.TABLEKEY
                                                            AND I2.TABLEID = INSL.TABLEID
                                                            AND I2.INSLCODE = INSL.INSLCODE
                                                            AND I2.INSLEND > INSL.INSLEND ) )
            )
ORDER BY LEAS.SUITID
```

Comment: If the question si for sql server why do you tag mysql ?... remove the tag not related to your question please

Comment: ok..................................

Comment: Where is the alias `LEAS` even defined?  I see it nowhere.

Comment: ok writing the full query !!

Comment: Format your code. I doubt anyone would be willing to go through the trouble of helping you otherwise.

Comment: done ................

Answer (score 4):

I think you have missed a bracket. Please verify it by adding a closing bracket @

```
'140917', '140938' ))
```

In below where clause

```
AND ( LEAS.BLDGID IN ( '140056', '140063', '140070', '140104',
                           '140137', '140138', '140151', '140253',
                           '140345', '140419', '140444', '140508',
                           '140509', '140522', '140542', '140546',
                           '140570', '140575', '140579', '140590',
                           '140623', '140625', '140626', '140662',
                           '140666', '140670', '140760', '140763',
                           '140788', '140789', '140793', '140799',
                           '140811', '140852', '140858', '140861',
                           '140867', '140875', '140880', '140881',
                           '140917', '140938' )
```

Comment: @DeepakJain: If the answer is solve your problem, you can select this as accepted answer.